# Copy files that match a list of metadata (size, timestamp, extension)

Tags: php, windows, file, powershell

I am writing a script to copy, from A to B,  only those files whose metadata matches a list.txt file.

The list.txt file contains the length (size), LastWriteTime, and filename.ext for each files to be copied. For example:

```
"5475891","2017-02-18 20:28:22","aaa.JPG"
"555109","2017-06-22 06:59:34","bbb.pdf"
"56363","2017-06-30 22:44:48","uuu.docx"
"638700","2017-07-31 18:41:43","uuu.docx"
"647053","2014-08-15 20:56:28","ppp.jpg"
"78725","2017-08-02 05:55:57","fff.php"
"79946","2017-08-02 06:42:03","kkk.pdf"
"8404037","2016-05-19 05:58:20","iii.pdf"
"85957","2017-07-31 22:44:23","777.pdf"
```

**Every** file on A, recursively, that is 100% match in **length**, **LastWriteTime**, and **.ext(extension)** (*disregard filename characters before the .ext!*) is to be copied to B, preserving the directory tree structure present in A. (No overwrites or deletions in either A or B).

I am stuck with the script:

```
$Source=Get-Content list.txt
Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object  length, lastwritetime, GetExtension
foreach($item in $Source){
    $file = gci -filter $("*{0}*" -f $item)
    if ($file -ne $null)
    {
        Copy-Item $file A: B:
    }
}
```

Suggestions on what I am doing wrong? PowerShell or PHP.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: I am trying in powershhel but interested/open for a php solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First read the list as a csv file
- I'd then build a hash table with one unique key from the list elements
- then iterate the source, build the key and check if present in the hash table
- if found construct destination by replacing the root of A with the root of B and copy

`Get-Help command` will supply the correct syntax of every command.

**EDIT** changed to use the complete date time as part of the key and use lower case extension
**EDIT2** Inserted an `if` to check if $Destination folder exists, if not create it. This did work perfectly on a local test.

```
## Q:\Test\2017\08\25\SO_45872202.ps1

$Source = "Q:\Test\2017\"
$Target = "C:\Test\2017\"

$List = Import-Csv list.txt -Header Size,LastWriteTime,Name

$Hash = @{}
ForEach ($Row in $List){
    $Key = ("{0},{1},.{2}" -F $Row.Size,$Row.LastWriteTime,$Row.Name.Split('.')[-1].ToLower())
    IF (!($Hash[$Key])) {$Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name)}
}
$Hash | Format-Table -Auto

Get-Childitem -Path $Source -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $Key = ("{0},{1},{2}" -F $_.Length,($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),$_.Extension.ToLower())
    #$Key
    If ($Hash[$Key]){
        $Destination = $_.FullName -Replace "^$([RegEx]::Escape($Source))","$Target"
        If (!(Test-Path (Split-Path $Destination))){MD (Split-Path $Destination)|Out-Null}
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination #-WhatIf
    }
}
```

If the output looks OK remove the trailing `-WhatIF` from the Copy-Item

Comment: very nice! it works, although it does seem to skip/ignore (i.e., does not copy) files with a subset of extensions (e.g., .txt, .csv) that should be copied, yet works on other extensions as expected. i am trying to troubleshoot the reason.

Comment: It was rather late (3am) when I decided to use ticks to avoid date/time formats differences. But I fear the date/time from the list doesn't contain fractional seconds while the real file will do. I'll reowrk that.

Comment: Different casing of the extension as a possible reason eliminated.

Comment: Many thanks for the extension fix!  It does not copy files that are within a directory in A:, for example, A:\dir\foo.txt:
`Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'B:\dir\foo.txt'.
At line:18 char:14`.  The goal, is that any and all files in **A: and its entire subdir tree** that match 100% the list.txt entries should be copied from A to B, along with the dir structure they occupy in A.

Comment: You should have had errors you didn't report about missing pathes, issue solved by creating pathes. See changed script.

Comment: very elegant. thank you very much for making it work!

Comment: small problem (probably ?) with the `$Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name)` line: if there are **more than one** matching files in A: (e.g., in subdirectories or with different filenames [yet same size, LWT, .ext, so they should be copied to B w/o error message:]) the following error message is displayed (although the files seem to be properly copied to B:): `Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 
'28149,2017-08-24 21:43:01,.txt....`

Comment: `Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 
'28149,2017-08-24 21:43:01,.txt'  Key being added: '28149,2017-08-24 21:43:01,.txt'"
At line:9 char:5
+     $Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException`

Comment: Since the key is already in the hash table, every file matching the same key is copied, so simply ignore the error. You might append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or it's abbrev. `-EA 0` to the `$Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name) -EA 0`

Comment: `At line:9 char:31
+     $Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name) -EA 0
+                               ~~~
Unexpected token '-EA' in expression or statement.
At line:9 char:35
+     $Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name) -EA 0
+                                   ~
Unexpected token '0' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Comment: Sorry didn't test it this time, inserted an if to check for presence of the key.

Comment: Is there a easy way to make the script do exactly the **opposite**: i.e., copy all files from `Q:\Test\2017` except the ones whose metadata is on the list.txt?